# How to provide condition to the parameter

Tags: bash, arguments

While providing external parameter values should have before and after hyphen. If  hyphen is not there it should reflect the error stating that the hyphen should be needed before and after the text.

For example: the external parameter should be

```
-report-country-sales-price-
```

Comment: Your argument string has five dashes (hyphens). Which dash is the one that needs to be present specifically? Does your script take other arguments?

Comment: This is basically second parameter it should have 7 dashes(hyphens) i.e
-report-country-sales-price-ext-fxt-

Comment: if hyphens is missing it should provide an error

Comment: This is different from what you show in your question though, so now nobody knows what you mean.

Comment: mainly parameter should have before and after hyphens

Comment: Ok, and this is the _only_ argument to the script? You mentioned something about a _second_ parameter... Should the test be done on _all_ parameters?

Comment: So any of these could be valid? `-a-` `-a-b-` `-a-b-c-` `-a-b-c-d-e-`, etc. ad nauseum? What about `-a--b-`?

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: it should be only one hyphens before and after the parameter and maximum should be 6 as  below;
-start-end-below-upper-close-end-

Comment: That string has 7 hyphens, not 6.  It would be good if you could update the actual text of your question with all this additional info instead of giving inconsistent comments.

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, you can do things like:

```
case $1 in
  (-*-) ;; # OK
  (*) echo >&2 "The first parameter must start and end with a -"; exit 1
esac
```

For a more specific matching, in `bash` specifically:

```
regex='^-([[:alpha:]]+)-([[:alpha:]]+)-([[:alpha:]]+)-([[:alpha:]]+)-$'
if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
  A=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  B=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  C=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  D=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
else
  echo >&2 "First parameter must be -letters-letters-letters-letters-"
  exit 1
fi
```

Or to allow a variable number of `-` delimited words:

```
regex='^(-[[:alpha:]]+){2,6}-$'
if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
  IFS=- read -ra words <<< "$1" # OK here as $1 is guaranteed not to
                                # contain newline characters at this
                                # point.
  A=${words[1]}
  B=${words[2]}
  C=${words[3]-not-supplied}
  D=${words[4]-not-supplied}
  E=${words[5]-not-supplied}
  F=${words[6]-not-supplied}
else
  echo >&2 "First parameter must be list of 2 to 6 - separated words"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: if [[ $parameter 2 != "(-*-)"]];then
echo "Second parameter must start and end with -". but this script is not working, please assist

Comment: @Giri,  you can do `[[ $2 != -*- ]]` in Korn-like shells, though that has little advantage over the standard `case $2 in (-*-)...` syntax.